# Python. File open procedure

Tags: python, tcl

How could the following code (written in TCL) be translated in Python 2.7?

```
set types {{"Text file" ".txt"} {"All Files" "*.*"}}
set file [tk_getOpenFile -filetypes $types -parent . -initialdir [pwd]]
if {$file=={}} {return}
set f [open $file r]
set fullPath [file rootname $file]
set name [lrange [split $fullPath "/"] end end]
```

Comment: I added the `tcl` tag, because at the very least you'll want an answer from someone who knows both languages. However, you should make an attempt at translating it yourself first, and ask about specific points you are having trouble with. If you don't know Python, a tutorial would be a good starting place.

Comment: Thanks for your council. I will try to ask about specific points.

Comment: Do you care about the `fullPath` value, or is that just a means to an end? (read: you can get the filename in python without first getting the root name)

Comment: The main problem is to achieve the opening of a window with a list of the current directory files.

Comment: Have you done any research? A simple google search of "tkinter file dialog" yields plenty of results.

Comment: Yes. I looked for already in Google, and directly on the website (https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/index.htm). But I have found nothing concrete.
I want that when pressing the button the window with the list of files (with use of the glob module to filter on a file format) and further reading the chosen file opened.

Comment: I will create a new question with piece of my code that does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the file dialog you must import [tkFileDialog](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-file-dialogs.htm). It can be used like this:

```
import tkFileDialog
import os               # so we can call getcwd()
...
types = (("Text file", ".txt"), ("All Files", "*.*"))
file = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=types, initialdir=os.getcwd())
```

To open the file, there are many ways. A literal translation would be:

```
f = open(file, "r")
```

A more pythonic way would be with the `with` statement:

```
with open(file, "r") as f:
    <code to work with the file here>
```

Note that if you want to get the path and open it at the same time you can use `askopenfile` rather than `askopenfilename`. In that case, `askopenfile` will return the equivalent of `f` in the tcl code.

The [os.path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) module gives you plenty of functions for working with filenames.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help !